# How do you change the width of an li flex-row element in Tailwind?

Tags: flexbox, width, html-lists, tailwind-css

[image]

I am trying everything in the Tailwind docs, but I can't seem to change how wide my first li element is.

```
<section class="overflow-hidden">
        <ul class="bg-gray-200 flex flex-row items-center overflow-scroll w-full">
            <li class="bg-white px-4 text-left w-96">Why won't this thing change width?</li>
            <li class="px-4">Google</li>
            <li class="px-4">Microsoft</li>
            <li class="px-4">Netflix</li>
            <li class="px-4">Facebook</li>
            <li class="px-4">Marvel</li>
            <li class="px-4">Disney</li>
        </ul>
</section>
```

I have tried adding these tags to the first li element in the list

- w-full
- w-screen
- w-96
- basis-1/2
- basis-full
- basis-80

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem with your codes. Please provide more details or screenshots about the issue.

Comment: @SibevinWang I added a screenshot of the issue for context. I was wondering if a tailwind preset is forcing the width of the li element to fit the content, but changing width is normally so easy that I can't imagine this being true.

Comment: if you use `w-96`(or others you listed above), it means the `li` width is fixed. If you want  the `li` width to fits  the content inside, you should use flex `grow` or `shrink` to define the `li` width behavior since you put `li` in a `ul.flex`.

Answer (score 0):

Elements inside a flex div will try to fit in the available space. It's a natural behavior and that's why your div is not able to grow.
To change this behavior, you'll need to add a `flex-shrink: 0`, or, in a tailwind way, add a `shrink-0` class.

Here is an example:

```
<section class="overflow-hidden">
  <ul class="bg-gray-200 flex flex-row items-center overflow-scroll w-full">
    <li class="bg-white px-4 text-left w-96 shrink-0">Why won't this thing change width?</li>
    <li class="px-4">Google</li>
    <li class="px-4">Microsoft</li>
    <li class="px-4">Netflix</li>
    <li class="px-4">Facebook</li>
    <li class="px-4">Marvel</li>
    <li class="px-4">Disney</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```